# How to stop redirecting url on MAMP?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, mamp

I have been working with MAMP without any problem, but now I've finished my website, and my computer is still redirecting to my local files. I erased my site host, but still continues redirecting to MAMP. How I can delete this redirect?  I've tried turning off MAMP.

Thanks in advance.